# Use shorter package names to resolve conflicting name

Tags: java, namespaces, package

Is there a way to use a shortened package name in Java if you have conflicting names?

For instance, instead of typing out `com.domain.a.b`, if the conflict is in `com.domain.a`, you can just say `b.SomeClass` instead of `com.domain.a.b.SomeClass`. C# has a feature similar to this.

Comment: Very short answer: no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you either use fully qualified names or short names. You're probably looking for [obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2)

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these
>   situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen
>   in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference
>   to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a
>   visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that
>   such a declaration is obscured.

If you follow Java naming conventions, you shouldn't really have any issues.