# Reusing part of the path to packages for classes with same name

Tags: java, import

I have two classes both name Foo. one is in package ver_one, and the other is in package ver_two.

Obviously I can't import both, so I use them with their full class names.
The problem is that the full name is com.org.oh.my.god.why.is.this.package.name.so.long.ver_one & ver_two, respectively.

So if I have a point in the code where I need both, it will look like this:

```
 public com.org.oh.my.god.why.is.this.package.name.so.long.ver_one.Foo translate(com.org.oh.my.god.why.is.this.package.name.so.long.ver_two.Foo other) {
          return new com.org.oh.my.god.why.is.this.package.name.so.long.ver_one.Foo(other.getID());
    }
```

I would have liked to not have this repeat throughout the code. I can always import one of the two, but it's a only slightly better.
I would prefer something along the lines of:

```
import com.org.oh.my.god.why.is.this.package.name.so.long.*;

public ver_one.Foo translate(ver_two.Foo other) {
      return new ver_one.Foo(other.getID());
}
```

In other languages it can be done with macros or something along those lines.
Couldn't find something parallel in java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use shorter package names to resolve conflicting name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174033/use-shorter-package-names-to-resolve-conflicting-name)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882351/address-a-package-name-by-a-shorter-name and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447880/change-name-of-import-in-java-or-import-two-classes-with-the-same-name

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with an IDE like Eclipse you have the option to automtically organize your imports, i would suggest you to take a look at that, it is a pretty useful function since it automatically deletes unused(not needed) imports and ads the ones you need.

Another option would be to use the star "*" (or however it is called):

```
com.org.oh.my.god.why.is.this.package.name.so.long.*
```

but that would import all classes that are inside of the package long.

Anyways, you shouldn't create 2 Objects(classes) of the same name, it can mostly be prevented.